# Angular : How do i create modules such that lazy loaded modules have access to the modules imported in AppModule?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

As far as i know creating a SharedModule and importing it in AppModule and LazyLoadedFeature Modules would mean that the shared module would be loaded twice when both modules (App , LazyLoadedFeature) would be loaded. How Can i structure the Modules such that once imported in app the imported Modules are made available to all the underlying LazyLoadedFeatureModules .

Comment: then it wont be a lazy loaded modules if all the modeuls of app are loaded in shared module. you need to create a shared module for both app and shred module to use\

Comment: not all , for example FormsModule and other modules provided by angular .All featureModules which are lazyloaded have to access these modules from app

Comment: then create main module which is the base module and used in all app and shared module

Comment: it won't be loaded twice, it will be cached. you will however have new instances of providers if shared modules define some. read [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)